# How to make tables like ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD(GA360 export table) in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to put together multiple tables with:
1. same schema
2. same name with different suffix just like tables that is created when GA360 data is exported to Bigquery

See my [table list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWkSa.png)  in the Bigquery UI.

I want to put together from new_1 , new_2, new_3 tables to  new_(3)
  just like ga_sessions_(366)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! These are called sharded tables, all you need to do to allow BigQuery to group these tables, as it does with the Google Analytics export data, is give them the same table name prefix. Note that **this only works when they are in a date form**, like `_20200101`.

For example the following tables:

```
my_data_20200101
my_data_20200102
my_data_20200103
```

Will appear in BigQuery as:

```
my_data_
```

And can be queried with wildcards:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_data_*`
```

Or with data ranges by transforming the suffix:

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_data_*`
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) = DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

You can find more information in the [official BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard).

Comment: Ben's answer is correct and as you will see also in the documentation he provided, it is a better practice to use partitioned tables instead. 
Sharded tables must maintain a copy of the schema and metadata for each date-named table. Also BigQuery might be required to verify permissions for each queried table. These impact query performance.

Comment: thanks, Ben!  so, if i just make table with same suffix, bigquery automatically change tables into sharded table. I'm not sure why table that I created new_1, new_2, new_3 doesn't appear as new_.

Comment: BigQuery only displays suffixes together when they are in a date form, like `_20200101`. This is only an UI choice, the data underneath has not changed.