# how to group a table in BigQuery by day and insert it using SDK?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new in BigQuery, so I am sorry if I don't use the correct term in BigQuery.

I usually use BigQuery and stream the data from Google Analytics. but the Google set it automatically. I want to create something like this using my own data

[image]

as you can see, the `events_` table has 150 'part', the parts are actually a day. as you can see, it is separated by Year, Month and day. and eventually I can perform query using `_TABLE_SUFFIX`

my questions are:

1. how to create/set up a table like that? I don't know what it is called in BigQuery. do I have to create it manually or by code ?
2. how to insert the data to the correct part of the table (to correct year month day) using SDK? I am currently using Python SDK, but it is ok if you can show using other language

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of tables are called `Sharded Tables`.

As answered by @Betjens in this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194094/how-to-create-sharded-table-in-gcp-bigquery/70204908#70204908) , Sharded tables are generated automatically once google-bigquery finds tables that share the following characteristics:

- Exist in the same dataset.
- Have the exact same table schema.
- The same prefix.
- Have a suffix of the form _YYYYMMDD. (eg. 20230720)

For Example, if you create 5 tables like `TableName\_YYYYMMDD` format (Prefix will be name of the table, which is same for all the 5 tables and suffix will be in the form of YYYYMMDD format), they will be grouped once we refresh the BigQuery UI

```
demoTable_20230801
demoTable_20230802
demoTable_20230803
demoTable_20230804
demoTable_20230805
```

We can query this table using wildcards.

```
Select * from `Project_name.dataset_name.demoTable_*`
```

For more information, you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dt_partition_shard) and this [stack case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784005/18329678) as well.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.